# Routine for a fairly inactive person with a really bad knee and ankle

Tags: workout-routines, strength, body-fat, routine

I am trying to get back into exercising again. I used to do it religiously 6 days a week and then life happened and I got out of my routine. I want to get back into a routine to get me to a point of health I should be in again. Below is some information about me and about what my goals are and what I am looking for.

**About**

Age 34

Height 6' 2"

Weight 244 lbs

Knees - Bad (simple leg curls of 60 lbs hurt (30lbs per leg), so I don't do them)

Body Fat % ~ 30% (guestimate from Withings App)

BMI - about the same not interested in it due to it's failure when muscle mass is high

**Goals:**

Looking for a physique similar to that of a "Strong Man" body type with no need for a six-pack or to be that large, not looking for a "shredded" physique that is typical of many "Cross Fit".

**Looking for**

Resources to getting an adequate routine together along with some healthy eating tips and ways to not pay a fortune for healthy food that is also not arduous to prepare. I am not looking to get on the competition journey, just looking for a healthier body.

Thank you for any advice and ask away if needed.

Comment: Does squatting or walking cause you pain?

Comment: Squats, do, after a bit start to become bother some, so I try to limit the total amount I do. I am now trying to keep some data on my exercises to see when things occur, etc. Walking sometimes causes ankle swelling even with my orthodics, but the elliptical seems to prevent most of that (I do infrequently get stiff knee from it though)

Comment: Were you prescribed orthotics? Have you had your knees checked out? Also, what kinds of activities do you enjoy? It would do no good to recommend a low impact activity such as swimming if you hate the water :)

Comment: The orthotics are prescribed. I have not had my knees looked at in a while but the last time I did my PCP did notice my knee caps moving more than they should and suggested some sort of light knee exercise to get the strengthback. I love using the eliptical, it's probably my favorite exercise since I love to walk and it's easier on me. I do like doing the circut training too.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with bodyweight exercises as they are less taxing for the body yet challenging. You are your own Gym from Mark Lauren is nice, as it starts really slow and adds up progressivelly by changing the exercise variation and the leverage of the body. Another more 'flexible' guideline would be never gymless by Ross Enamait.